# How to activate RealityKit gestures for Model entity?

Tags: swift, arkit, realitykit

In the code below, I create a model entity and load a 3d model named "stone". I then set `generateCollisionShapes` to true. I should then be able to install gestures to the view but I'm getting an error saying my model entity doesn't conform to the type 'HasCollision'.

I need some help getting this to work. Any feedback is appreciated.

```
import ARKit
import RealityKit

class Coordinator: NSObject {
    
    weak var view: ARView?
            
    @objc func handleTap(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        guard let view = self.view else { return }            
        let tapLocation = recognizer.location(in: view)
        
        let results = view.raycast(from: tapLocation, 
                               allowing: .estimatedPlane, 
                              alignment: .horizontal)
        
        if let result = results.first {
            
            let anchor = AnchorEntity(raycastResult: result)
            
            guard let modelEntity = try? ModelEntity.load(named: "stone") 
            else {
                print("didn't find model")
                return
            }                
            modelEntity.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
            anchor.addChild(modelEntity)                
            view.scene.addAnchor(anchor)                                
            view.installGestures(.all, for: modelEntity)    
        }            
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Entity.loadModel(...)` method instead of `ModelEntity.load(...)`

```
guard let modelEntity = try? Entity.loadModel(named: "stone") else { return }

modelEntity.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)

arView.installGestures([.all], for: modelEntity as Entity & HasCollision)
```

P. S.

- It's not good to declare an ARView object as UIView's `view` – declare it as `arView`.

Comment: Thanks for helping out. I did try adding "as! Entity & HasCollision" but when I run the project I get the error Argument type 'Entity' does not conform to expected type 'HasCollision'

Comment: I've updated my answer to cover your case.